# Read data from SD card of ds150e

Tags: filesystem, sd-card

Ubuntu does not recognize SD card of delphi ds150e. GParted sees SD card, but filesystem is not marked. How to read data from SD card?
I don't know which filesystem uses ds150e device.
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You can go on by checking if the open source equivalents of the most used drive formats is installed by opening a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and typing:

```
apt-cache policy ntfs-3g exfat-fuse dosfstools
```

Which should if they are installed an output like this:

```
ntfs-3g:
  Installed: 1:2015.3.14AR.1-1build1
  Candidate: 1:2015.3.14AR.1-1build1
  Version table:
 *** 1:2015.3.14AR.1-1build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
exfat-fuse:
  Installed: 1.2.3-1
  Candidate: 1.2.3-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.2.3-1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
dosfstools:
  Installed: 3.0.28-2ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 3.0.28-2ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.0.28-2ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.0.28-2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

If one of the installed lines shows `(none)`instead of a version number you can install the driver by:

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>*
```

Comment: In windows the SD card also does not recognize.

Comment: `ntfs-3g` - 1:2013.1.13AR.1-2ubuntu2 AND `exfat-fuse` - 1.0.1-1 0

Comment: O.k. then I'm lost as well no clue which file-system this card is using then, sure it is formatted at all and containing data?

Comment: Through `Delphi` program and `DS-150E` device is possible to read the data. I don't know which file system uses the storage device.

Comment: I'll dig into this and post an answer when i found the solution, but my guess right now is, that it might be some kind of special format.

Comment: So i not did a bit of digging with my friend google and found out that the cards seem to be formatted as FAT or FAT32, i added that into my answer, but i think those should be installed on your system as well.

Comment: CPU `DS-150E` - http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/microcontrollers/stm32-32-bit-arm-cortex-mcus/stm32f2-series/stm32f2x5/stm32f205zg.html#quickview-scroll

Comment: `dosfstools` - 3.0.26-1

Comment: @zerg if it isn't recognized in Windows, it could be an issue with the card or the reader. Is Windows on the same computer, and have you tried the card in another computer?

Comment: I tried in another computer (ubuntu/ windows 8). My computer (ubuntu/windows 7).